# Trigger Docker update from git push

Tags: git, docker, gatsby

I have recently started working with `Docker` in a simple environment.

I have created a simple blog with the static website generator [gatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org).

I have containerized my app with docker:

```
//Dockerfile

FROM node:11.9.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install  
RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli


COPY . . 

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gatsby", "develop", "-H", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Everything has been pushed and deployed on my server and works as expected.

Each blog post is a markdown file read by gatsbyjs.

My understanding is when all my app will be ready (javascript, css, etc), the only thing I will update is the repository where my posts (markdown files) are as I add a new post.

I think the workflow to adopt is something like:

1. I wrote a new markdown file
2. push it to github
3. trigger a new image and container creation (right?)

[image]

Do I have to recreate a new image and container just for a new blog post added?

How can I trigger those actions in my server when the changes are pushed? Which tools should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to trigger a push event you can use hooks.
https://githooks.com/

If you don't want to build a new image every time you add a blog post, you could map the **markdowns** path to your host. This way you can just put a new markdown file into the mapped volume on your host and your container can use it. 
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Example:
Add following options to your run order.
docker run ... **-v /docker/data/...:/data**

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes I played with dicker volume but on local. Don't know if mapping a github repo would work, but I'll definitively check your approach

Comment: oh but you mean the markdown repo would be in my server but outside of the container right ?

Comment: Yes you could put your repo on your host.